# Can a particle attach to a counter?

Tags: grammar, particles, counters

I saw [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47894/7944) to a recent question which contained the sentence:

> 私は**猫二匹が**います

Is it okay to put the particle が after the counter. It seems strange to me. I would have expected:

> 私(に)は**猫が二匹**います

The answer to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32539/use-of-number-counter-as-a-noun) tells me that number+counter can be treated as a noun, so putting が at the end should be fine. But somehow I feel that the two situations are different.

In summary, is 私は**猫二匹が**います correct and why/when would I choose it instead of 私は**猫が二匹**います?

Comment: 「私は猫二匹がいます。」 is a very unnatural sentence and is something practically no native speakers would ever say (even though that answer got multiple upvotes).    Your own sentence is far better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form of a noun compound with a counter itself is grammatically correct, as you already read it.

As for when to use, I imagine situations where you treat several units each of which is comprised of single or multiple things as in military operation or something.

For example, if you ask for taking any two plates, you would say 皿を二枚取ってくれ, and refer to them as 皿二枚は when you tell how to arrange them.