# How to say "a year has 12 months"?

Tags: grammar

一年は十二ヶ月があります.

I'm trying to say "a year has 12 months" or "there are 12 months in a year." Is the above sentence correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply say:

> 一年は十二ヶ月です。

With あります, we natives definitely say it **without が**.

> 一年は十二ヶ月あります。

Even though 「～**には**～**があります**」is a basic correct structure, when it comes to **amount/number** of something, we seem to definitely prefer it without が, :

> 一年には十二ヶ月あります。

I find we definitely say it with が when talking about the seasons:

> 一年には四季があります。

It's possible to say:

> 一年には季節が四つあります。[But never <strike>四つがあります</strike>]

---

[Replying to additional request]

> Could you explain why we don't say 一年は四季です or 一年には12ヶ月があります (even though 一年は12ヶ月です and 一年には四季があります both mean "A year has ~~") ?

I believe it's because **だ・です・である** are to ***describe the subject***, and also it's because we treat the words of ***amount/number*** as if they are ***adverbs***.

> 一年は四季です

I don't say this is wrong, but I think you feel as though you're reading a metaphor.

I believe you don't have any problem with

> 一年には四季があります,

but I know you won't say

> <strike>一年には四季あります</strike>

Here, we see that we don't treat 四季 in the same way as １２か月 or １０kg. We say この箱は１０kgあります, but we never say この箱は１０kgがあります。(I'm already getting used to １年には１２か月があります, however) １年には１２か月あります sounds just the right.

We say
会議は明日です。
But we don't say
会議は明日がです nor 会議は明日にです。
It's because the words like 明日 or 去年 or 当日 are acting like adverbs in this usage.

> *Ref:* 名詞でありながら、文中であたかも副詞的なものとして機能する場合がある。例えば「昔・昨日・来年」「以前・以後・後日」などは、そのまま（つまり格助詞を伴わないで）文末の述語を修飾することができる。さらに「子供が３人遊んでいる」「夏休み中に小説を10 冊読んだ」の中の数量名詞も、その働きは副詞的である。(Source: [日本語教師のページ | 名詞の副詞的用法](http://www.nihongokyoshi.co.jp/manbow/manbow.php?id=930&TAB=1))

Comment: Just to emphasize your last point, you will never grammatically see counter + があります。 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47925/22352

Comment: Or, for that matter, counter + particle in general, except with の

Comment: Could you explain why we don't say 一年**は**四季**です** or 一年**には**12ヶ月**があります** (even though 一年**は**12ヶ月**です** and 一年**には**四季**があります** both mean "A year has ~~")  ?

Comment: @Chocolate I've added the answer in the answer section. :)