# Why is the を particle used twice here

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-を

I came across this sentence in the basic kanji book

> くつ**を**一足とくつ下を四足買いました

The sentence has two を particles even though I thought the を particles can only be used once in a sentence.  I thought since the と particle connects two nouns together it would look like this:

> くつの一足**と**くつ下の四足を買いました

Is this not possible or is the whole grammar wrong?
Why is it like that?

Comment: It might be case #2 listed here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16289/4892 -- A repeated verb has been left out ("backward gapping"):
XがAを、そしてYがBを買った　→　XがAを(買い)、そしてYがBを買った

Comment: @landonepps I believe that the first sentence is correct. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/8165/22352

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This を particle does not necessarily represent the object marker. Let's explore why.

> くつを一足　(one pair of shoes)

This を is used in connection with counters.  It does not necessarily indicate a direct object here.  According to the answer found [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/8165/22352) (and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17832/22352)), when working with counters, you can use the following structure:

> (Noun) (Particle) (Number + Counter) (Verb/Verb Phrase)

But where is the verb in this case?  So far, we have `Noun を Number + Counter` but no Verb.  This is because there is yet another noun used in relation to the verb. (You aren't just buying a pair of shoes, you're also buying a pair of socks.)

The key here is the fact that there is a と in this sentence.  In this case, と is used for making a list--translated to `and` in this case.

I want to make a special note that `くつを一足` is a noun phrase.  In other words, it acts like a single noun in terms of sentence creation. The same goes with `くつ下を四足.`  These both combine to be the direct object.  This grammar structure is not uncommon, as you will see in the other answers above, but a good rule of thumb goes like this:

> (Noun) (Particle) (Number + Counter) と (Noun) (Particle) (Number + Counter)
>    (repeat if necessary)+ (Verb/Verb Phrase)
>
> くつを一足とくつ下を四足 + Verb Phrase (one pair of shoes and four pairs of socks + verb phrase)

So what's the direct object?  In this case, it's the part of the sentence just above in yellow.  `One pair of shoes, and four pairs of socks` is our direct object.

We are combining two different ideas into one sentence here:

> くつを一足買いました。
>
> くつ下を四足買いました。

Putting it together, we can either say:

> くつを一足とくつ下を四足買いました。
>
> くつ下を四足とくつを一足買いました。

Should we include the counters as part of the direct object?  Well a direct object applies to a noun.  The phrase `noun+number+counter` is a noun phrase, acting as a noun.  So I would say yes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you but could you tell me if my assumption is correct we didn't include the 四足 in the direct object phrase because it acts as an adjective?

Comment: @Hamzeh, I updated my answer.  Please be sure to read the whole answer, as I edited parts in the middle as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your version is possible, but we don't usually say it in that way.

> くつを一足とくつ下を四足買いました。
>
> 一足のくつと四足のくつ下を買いました。

These two are natural.

When we say '一足買いました,' this 一足 is an adverb. In other words, we don't buy something named '一足'.

> くつを**一足**買いました。[一足 in 一足買う is an ***adverb***]
>
> **一足の**くつを買いました。[一足の is an ***adjective***]

---

[Edit to add]
I've noticed I haven't answered the title question.

> **Why is the を particle used twice here**

That is because each of these nouns (くつ and くつ下) is needed to be indicated as the object of the verb.
I parse the sentence as two ***adverb phrases*** connected with と.

> [くつを一足 (*adv*)] と [くつ下を四足 (*adv*)] 買いました。

When we have two items as the subject of a verb, we say

> くつが一足 と くつ下が四足 あります。

くつを一足 or くつが一足 alone doesn't stand very good as a noun to native's ears, and is needing a verb.

▶ You can also say it as follows; without the particle in the middle, くつ一足、くつ下四足, they become nouns, and you need the particle, を, once, right after the whole phrase.

> くつ一足とくつ下四足(と)を買いました。[the second と is usually omitted]

But when it's くつを 一足 買いました, this 一足 is an adverb modifying the verb, 買いました.

> *Cf:*「子供が３人遊んでいる」「夏休み中に小説を10 冊読んだ」の中の数量名詞も、その働きは副詞的である。
>   (Source: 日本語教師のページ | [名詞の副詞的用法](http://www.nihongokyoshi.co.jp/manbow/manbow.php?id=930&TAB=1))
>
> Also see: [How to say "a year has 12 months"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/50292/how-to-say-a-year-has-12-months/50293#50293)