# Counters with and without の

Tags: particle-の, counters

I'm currently reading a short paragraph [here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-lessons/1-3-the-north-wind-and-the-sun/) that has the following sentences:

> 男{おとこ}はそう言{い}うと、もう一枚{いちまい}マントを出{だ}して、急{いそ}いで着{き}ました。北風{きたかぜ}は二{に}枚{まい}のマントを脱{ぬ}がせるために、もっと強{つよ}く風{かぜ}を吹{ふ}きました。

In particular, the first sentence uses the counter directly without の as 一枚{いちまい}マント, while the second uses it with a の as 二{に}枚{まい}のマント.

I checked this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47925/can-a-particle-attach-to-a-counter) for particles after counters, but that's for different particles. Looking at [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36890/questions-about-counters) that mentions の, it implies it should be either マント一枚{いちまい} or 一枚{いちまい}のマント. And yet, [this Tae Kim page](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/counting) on counters has this as an example:

> 紙｛かみ｝、二｛に｝枚｛まい｝ずつをホッチキスで留｛とど｝める。

which is without の, but I imagine that's an exception, as ずつ is a suffix and not a noun, and would perhaps be shuffled around into something like this:

> 二｛に｝枚｛まい｝の紙｛かみ｝ずつをホッチキスで留｛とど｝める。

However, I'm not too sure then if the original article's lack of の is a typo or if there's a slightly different meaning like the suffix.

Answer (score 3):

[数詞の副詞的用法 (adverbial usage of numerical expression)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12194768172) should answer your question.

All of below are acceptable and mean the same:

- もう一枚マントを出して
- マントをもう一枚出して
- もう一枚のマントを出して

In the first two, もう一枚 is used adverbially while in the last, combined with の, modifies マント.

In the second example, 二枚の紙ずつを is wrong.

- 紙二枚ずつを留める
- 紙を二枚ずつ留める

are both possible. The latter is the example of an adverbial usage, and sounds more natural to me.

Btw, 留める is read とめる in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the operative term would be "もう一枚" (one more/another), 一枚 comes with もうand not マント. You can rephrase it into マントをもう一枚出だして and it would mean the same.

Note that you could also say "もう一枚のマント", but that would mean "the other cape".

[See def 5.](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86)