# Grammar behind an object counter

Tags: grammar

Example:

> ビールを一杯飲む

> ビール一杯を飲む

> 一杯のビールを飲む

> ビールの一杯を飲む

As far as I can tell all of them are usable and valid. How is this floating state of the counter explained grammatically?

I presume it counts as an adverb in the first and maybe the second case? So in those cases you modify the verb, and in the other cases you modify the noun, leaving the verb pure?

Comment: Should answer your question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/88966/45489

Comment: Note that ビールの1杯を飲む is different. It means "to drink one cup's amount of the beer (e.g., in the tank)".