# What does 一人 mean in a sentence like this?

Tags: sentence, numbers

> こちらは負傷者を一人抱えている

"We are carrying a wounded person alone"

or is it

"We have one wounded person?"

In the second case why 一人 is placed after 負傷者

Comment: Should be a dup [Counters with and without の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84379)

Comment: I'm not sure what "We are carrying a wounded person alone" might mean.  It's a perfectly grammatical sentence, but the word "alone" confuses the whole thing.  Consider instead how Japanese uses counters and where it places them relative to what is being counted:  usually after the particle marking what's being counted.  This is a big clue to the most natural understanding of this sentence.

Comment: Was there some context that gave you the impression the subject of the sentence is "we"? If so, wouldn't that be weird to describe multiple people as doing something adverbially with 一人?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter, and there is basically no confusion (The first interpretation is not entirely impossible, but...).

To understand the strucutre, consider

> こちらは負傷者をたくさん抱えている (We have many wounded person).
>
> こちらは負傷者を n人 抱えている

I guess the placement has some freedom because the ひとり here works as an adverb.

You are right in that

> こちらは一人負傷者を抱えている

is similar in meaning.

Your confusion can also be justified, as in:

> （太郎は）悩みを一人[で]抱えている (He is carrying his worries alone = He doesn't open up).

---

I really can't seem to come up with a compelling and clear reason why the second interpretation is the only choice. Probably:

- こちらは…を抱えている structure is mostly used in situation where "we" are working as a team: "This side, we, have..." so carrying somebody alone doesn't fit
- （負傷者を）抱える in this case is more fugirative than physically carrying somebody
- If Alice and Bob are together taking care of a wounded person but you are carrying a wounded person only by yourself, you would say "こちらは負傷者を一人**で**抱えている"

Comment: The more I think the more I'm puzzled. 太郎: 「仕事が忙しくて大変だ，君にはわからないだろうけど」二郎: 「わからないだって！こっちは赤ん坊をひとり[で]抱えているんだぞ！」 は「で」がなくてもギリギリ二郎がひとりで助けを得られていないという解釈が行ける気がします…

Comment: IMO「こちらは危険な暗闇を一人歩いている」may work, but that baby example would **definitely** need 「で」 hands down