# Random Use of 一つ in お握りはどこかしら

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

I am looking at the lyrics of [お握りはどこかしら](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NerArbqcl7w) to help with Japanese recognition; the song is fast, but by deciphering the lyrics I can better recognize what is being said and keep up with the lyrics.

Thus far the song is very informal, but I am confused by this line:

> お母さんはもういないし、おうちに食べ物一つもないし…

The use of "一つ" here. I know it says "My mom is not here anymore (she left for [work]) and there is not a single piece of food in our house."

But is there anything grammatical about the use of 一つ here?

Comment: What makes you feel it's random? Because it's not 一つのたべもの? Related: [Counters with and without の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84379)

Comment: 一つの食べ物 does not make sense here, and 一つ is used after 食べ物. I could not find anything online regarding what 一つ actually adds to the sentence.

Comment: It depends on what you mean, but 一つの食べ物 basically means the same thing. It is simply unidiomatic.

Comment: I was under the assumption that 一つの[名詞] is "One [Noun]," while [名詞]の一つ meant "Type of [Noun]," but maybe I am forgetting grammar. Here, there is no の, so I did not want to assume anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds *even* (cf. [一つ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%B8%80%E3%81%A4/#je-63720) #6). Basically it adds emphasis to negation.

食べ物がない and 食べ物一つもない more or less correspond to *there is no food* and *there is not even a piece of food*.

Comment: Kind of what I thought, but I did not want to assume. Thank you.