# Rate/ratio: What are the differences between 「一年一万円」,「一年に一万円」,「一年で一万円」?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-で, counters

When describing a rate or ratio, what are the differences between no particle, に, and で?

Also related: In a JLPT N5 sample test booklet, I came across the sentence below.  Why is で used in the second sentence but not the first?

「それは　いくらですか。」「一つ　２００円です。三つで　５００円です。」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally counter-phrases can be used adverbially. As for 一つ in the sentence, that's why.

- [Counters with and without の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84379/45489)

So it can be 三つ５００円, too.

---

As for に vs で, に is more felt like ratio, i.e., 'per' whereas で more like 'adding up' (translationwise, it can be the usual *with* - with three of them,..).

Accordingly, 一年に一万円 sounds like '10000yen per year' = recurring 10000 yen (losing or getting); 一年で一万円 sounds like the resulting (cost or gain) 10000 yen after a year, not necessarily recurring. Of course, if the contexts make clear, both are interchangeable to some extent.

The choice of に/で also depends on the verb. If a counter-phrase is an indirect object, only に can be used:

- 一人に一万円渡した
- ?一人で一万円渡した (This means, if anything, *I handed 10000 yen alone*)

In the sentences in question, the counter-phrases are subjects and に cannot be used: 一つに２００円です won't work in that context. (Note that 一つに２００円かかりました would be fine since かかる can take に-phrase.)

Answer (score -1):

In this sentence, 「で」means something like "as for."
'One' is the most basic number, so there is no need to use 'as for'.
But it's also OK to say,「一つで200円です」.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Can you please add some examples or try to rephrase it?